# How do I find the proposal document(s) for an unicode character accepted in Unicode?

Tags: unicode, standards

How do I easily find all the documents related to a specific unicode character, starting from  the proposal document till any latest modifications to the same (if any)?

For example, if I wanted to find what the unicode character "ݜ" is for, how do I go about doing it? (assuming it is a newly encoded character which is not used much on the Internet)

(Just FYI, this is the [proposal document](https://unicode.org/L2/L2002/02274-arabic-ext.pdf) for the above character. What is the official way to track and find this?)

Comment: BTW, I am not sure if this is a meta question or if it's not relevant in this SE network. Please let me know if so, also pointing me where it should belong to. Thanks!

Comment: Today, there're 144,697 characters covering 159 modern and historical scripts. The best way to find out the function(s) of a character is to search it in Wikipedia, like this: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ݜ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ݜ) or find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters or here: https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html . Neither Unicode nor its characters are in the scope of Linguistics SE, it's a computer/technical question, there are lots of computer-related SEs, like Computer Science, Super User, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about linguistics.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But what if I am unable to find anywhere? Like for example: "ݔ".

Comment: For ݔ it's: 1. Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ݔ which takes you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode. 2. Search for ݔ on that page which takes you to the Arabic Supplement chart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Arabic_Supplement and tells you the code of ݔ is U+0754. 3. Go to the Arabic Supplement Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Supplement where you find links to proposal documents sorted by the character code, and 4. you open https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2003/03168-african-chars.pdf ad see ݔ is for _ny_ in Fulfulde of Senegal.

Comment: Thanks a lot  BTW, my point was just that there seems to be many other obscure unicode characters much more difficult to track and find, hence I just wanted to check if there's an official way to track things, like a codepoint-wise sorted registry/history.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an authoritative reference, but I tend to rely on the Wikipedia page for the Unicode block in question.

Looking at [the list of Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block), this character appears to be in [the Arabic Supplement block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Supplement). [The History section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Supplement#History) then links to all the proposals and discussions surrounding that block. [The first proposal there](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2002/02274-arabic-ext.pdf) (the same one you linked) mentions this character, SEEN WITH FOUR DOTS ABOVE, and explains the rationale:

> Writers of the Shina language in Kashmir, needing to write a retroflex /s/ letter, have adopted the convention of using a letter based on SHEEN but with four dots in place of three.

There are a few more paragraphs discussing graphical variants, and the appendix has various examples of use. At a quick glance, none of the other proposals touch on this character.